# Generalization of the linear extension theorem to directed acyclic graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, set-theory, order-theory

Using Zorn's lemma one can prove a generalization of the order extension theorem, that states any acyclic digraph is always contained in another acyclic unilaterally connected digraph on the same vertex set. With that said, if for any acyclic digraph $D$ we let $\mathcal{U}$ be the set of all unilaterally connected acyclic digraphs on the same vertex set as $D$ that contain $D$, then is it true that $D=\bigcap_{G\in\mathcal{U}}G$? If so then if we define $\text{dim}(D)$ to be the size of any minimum cardinality subset $S\subseteq \mathcal{U}$ that satisfies $D=\bigcap_{G\in S}G$. would this cardinal be the same as the order dimension of the poset $(V(D),\leq)$ where $u\leq v$ iff there is a directed walk from $u$ to $v$ in $D$? I'm pretty sure the first claim is true, and if it is then I know the order dimension of $(V(D),\leq)$ is less then or equal to the cardinal $\text{dim}(D)$, though I am curious if they are equal to each other.

---

To be more explicit the first statement is a generalization of the linear extension theorem since given an arbitrary partial-order $P=(X,\leq)$ we can define an acyclic digraph $D$ where $V(D)=X$ and $E(D)=\{(u,v)\in X\times X:u<v\}$ moreover if $G$ is any unilaterally connected acyclic digraph where $D\subseteq G$ and $V(G)=V(D)=X$ then we see that the poset $P'=(X,\preceq)$ where $u\preceq v$ iff there is a directed walk from $u$ to $v$ in $G$, must be an order extenstion of $P$ and it is linear becauuse $G$ is unilaterally connected which means the transitive closure $T$ of $E(G)$ is connex, that is for all $a,b\in X$ we have $(a,b)\in T$ or $(b,a)\in T$ or $a=b$.